# C++ - Decrypting a string from file

Tags: c++, arrays, matrix, encryption

As you can see from the title I need to decrypt the strings in a text file. I have major problems with this so if you can help me I would really appreciate it.

First of all, here is the input file:

```
saoreecessinntfi
pmrrj ie2
borj
```

I want to decrypt these words like this:

```
sesnaestocifreni
primjer 2
broj
```

I have used the matrix 4x4 to do this, and here is the code so far:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main() 
{
    ifstream test;
    test.open("test.txt");
    char word[5][5];
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
            test >> word[i][j];
        }
    }

     for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
            cout << word[j][i];
        }
    }   


    return 0;
}
```

Here is the output:

```
sesnaestocifreni
```

It only outputs the first word in text file. I think the problem with this is that I do not know how "long" is "i" and "j" in those other words beacuse the first word has 16 charachters so the counter "i" and "j" are set on 4. How to count each words charachters and if they are the same then decrpyt the word. Also if the word is right spelled I need to cout in the program "ERROR". For example

```
apple
```

I do not need to decrypt this word, beacuse it is right word, and "i" and "j" would not be the same or I do not know what I am talking about.

Comment: Your explanation is very confusing. Do you want to know how to process multiple blocks/lines? Do you want to reset the internal state after every 16 letters? Every line? Do you want to know how to deal with partial "blocks"?

Comment: `char word[5][5];` sorry but that is a five by five matrix, a four by four matirx is `char word[4][4];`. Thta's obvious isn't it, the number in the square brackets is the size of the array. Why is this so hard for beginners?

Comment: So I think you need to read each line into a string first. Then you can tell how big the line is and you can choose the right size of matrix to decrypt it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should work just the fine for your case:

```cpp
#include <cmath>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int matrixSize(std::string &str) {
    auto x = sqrt(str.length());
    return x - floor(x) == 0 ? x : 0;
}

int main() {
    std::fstream file("test.txt");
    std::string str;
    while (std::getline(file, str)) {
        if (int n = matrixSize(str)) {
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
                for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
                    std::cout << str.at(j * n + i);
            std::cout << std::endl;
        } else
            std::cout << "ERROR" << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Sample `test.txt` file:

```
saoreecessinntfi
pmrrj ie2
borj
apple
```

Output on [test run](https://wandbox.org/permlink/ioJVnwTbAAU3egUn):

```
sesnaestocifreni
primjer 2
broj
ERROR
```

Comment: It works perfectly. Thank you so much. But can you please just explaint the function MatrixSize? If it is not a problem. And if (n = MatrixSize(str)) please?

Comment: @SamedŠkulj `matrixSize` returns the square root of the length of passed string if it is perfect square else returns 0. The statement `if (int n = matrixSize(str))` simply means that we declaring `n`, storing in it the result `matrixSize` returns, and then checking if the value of `n` is true (non-zero), i.e. if the length of the string `str` is a perfect square. Checking for perfect square is necessary because it is the case when we can iterate both `i` and `j` to same value (`n`). PS: Length being a perfect square is the condition that tells if the string is already decrypted.

Comment: Ok now I get it. Thank you again

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your problem correctly, you are given a line of n*n characters and need to unscramble it as given.

```
while (true) {
    std::string line;
    std::getline(cin, line);
    if (line.empty())
       break;

    int n = 1;
    while (n*n < line.size()) {
        n++;
    }

    if (n*n != line.size()) {
        std::cout << "ERROR" << std::endl;
        continue;
    }

    std::string unscrambled;
    for (int col = 0; col < n; col++)
        for (int row = 0; row < n; row++)
            unscrambled.append(1, line[row * n + col]);

    std::cout << unscrambled << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: I swear I was really trying to understand this type of solution for this problem but I can not just figure out how to write "ERROR" for the lines that are not a perfect square amount of charachters. Can you atleast give some hint? Or solution if you are willing to, if not I undestand it

Comment: Replace `!=` by `<`. Check if `n*n == line.size()` after the loop.

Comment: Hmm what do you mean to check "n*n == line.size() after the loop"? I have changed the already while loop to < from != just like you have said.